# How to Freeze Header row in Excel using ExcelLibrary dll

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, excellibrary

I am using ExcelLibrary dll .

I want to Freeze the Header Row .. Can any body suggest how I might do this?

I have tried the following code..

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports ExcelLibrary
Imports ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet



Partial Class DownloadExcel
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        Dim wb As New Workbook()
        Dim sheetrowcounter As Integer
        sheetrowcounter = 0
        Dim sheet As New ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet.Worksheet("ExcelSheet")

        sheet.Cells(sheetrowcounter, 0) = New Cell("DELIVERY MONITORING SUMMARY(PROJECT GRANDE) ")
        sheet.Cells(sheetrowcounter, 2) = New Cell("")

        sheet.Cells(sheetrowcounter, 3) = New Cell("Report Date: '" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd H:mm:ss tt") & "                                                                                                                   ")

        sheetrowcounter += 1
        sheetrowcounter += 1
        sheet.Cells(sheetrowcounter, 0) = New Cell("Sl No")
        sheet.Cells.ColumnWidth(0) = 10000
        sheet.Cells(sheetrowcounter, 1) = New Cell("Name")
        sheet.Cells.ColumnWidth(1) = 6000

        sheetrowcounter += 1
        Dim t As DataTable = Session("exceltable")
        For i As Integer = 1 To t.Rows.Count - 1
            Try
                sheet.Cells(sheetrowcounter, 0) = New Cell(t.DefaultView.Item(i)(0))
                sheet.Cells(sheetrowcounter, 1) = New Cell(t.DefaultView.Item(i)(1))
                sheetrowcounter += 1
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        Next
        sheet.Cells(0, 0).Format.FormatString = "freeze"

        wb.Worksheets.Add(sheet)


        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DeliveryMonitoringSummaryDaily.xls")

        Dim m As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        wb.SaveToStream(m)
        m.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

I am Storing a Datatable with 2 columns and some Rows in the Session("exceltable") object..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience working with Excel Library you specified but I can to suggest to migrate to EPPlus library which is free and available on the http://epplus.codeplex.com/ site. This is very easy to use library with clear API and was designed to create advanced Excel 2007/2010 spreadsheets on the server. We used it successfully on several production projects. Using it you can achieve what you need by using ExcelSheet.View.FreezePanes method. I understand that my answer not answer your question, but it can be treated as alternative solution to you problem (I really don't know if you can or not to achieve what you need with Excel Library you specified).

Comment: Thanks for the reply..This May be the alternate, But my whole project uses the ExcelLibrary dll.. For only one page in my web site i need to change the whole project using epplus..

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Dim e As Worksheet
...
e.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1
e.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```